# Facebook comment moderating - unable to get control

Tags: facebook, joomla, facebook-comments

I can't seem to be able to moderate comments on my site
Here is the code I put under this link:
http://www.messianic.co.il/index.php/wall

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/he_IL/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=119904308062962";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>


<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://www.messianic.co.il" data-num-posts="100" data-width="1110"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fb:admins` should be a comma separates list of id's, i.e. remove the {}, and the same for the `fb:app_id`

Edit:

you need to change

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="{518305576}" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="{119904308062962}" />
```

to

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="518305576"/>
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="119904308062962" />
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what I need to do? I took this code from the Facebook comments page (I didn't make it on my own).

Comment: inside the <head>?
I changed it to:

<meta property="fb:admins" content="518305576"/>
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="119904308062962"/>

But still dosen't work :(

Comment: I did it, but still nothing, do I need to wait for facebook to refresh it's cache or something?